# Stop condition for recursion in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, transitive-closure

Here are the facts that I have in my knowledge base (http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/recursion.html (Recursion Exercise 2)):

```
taller(bob,mike).   % bob is taller than mike
taller(mike,jim).   % mike is taller than jim
taller(jim,george). % jim is taller than george
```

Now I want to use recursion to deduce something that is obvious "bob" is taller than "george".

I tried to add this rule to solve this:

```
taller(X,Y) :- taller(X,Z),taller(Z,Y).
```

I need your help to make a stop condition to this recursion because now I have a stack overflow error:

```
| ?- taller(bob,george).

Fatal Error: local stack overflow (size: 8192 Kb, environment variable used: LOCALSZ)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your recursive `taller/2` predicate is defined as:

```
taller(X,Y) :-
    taller(X,Z),
    taller(Z,Y).
```

As a result, a `taller/2` predicate can *always* result in two new `taller/2` predicates on the "call stack" so to speak, and this nesting can go on and on.

A way to handle this is **separating the knowledge from the transitive closure**. By defining an `is_taller/2` predicate, that calculates the *transitive closure* of the `taller/2` predicate like:

```
is_taller(X,Y) :-
    taller(X,Y).
is_taller(X,Y) :-
    taller(X,Z),
    is_taller(Z,Y).
```

Now there is "*guaranteed* progression" so to speak, because each time the `is_taller/2` is called, it will make a call to `taller/2`. Since `taller/2` has no recursion, the number of possible answers is limited. Since `taller/2` is a *strict* order relation, eventually we will reach the *shortest* person, and thus the backtracking will get exhausted.

So the full code should be:

```
taller(bob,mike).   % bob is taller than mike
taller(mike,jim).   % mike is taller than jim
taller(jim,george). % jim is taller than george

is_taller(X,Y) :-
    taller(X,Y).
is_taller(X,Y) :-
    taller(X,Z),
    is_taller(Z,Y).
```